# Passing arguments in a javascript function is not working

Tags: javascript

I am bit unclear in understanding why this below piece of code is not showing the message box,

http://jsfiddle.net/KendoDev/p8Mk2/

```
 function findMax(var x, var y) {

//alert("x is:" + x + " y is: " +y);
    var max = 0;
    if(x>y)
         max = x;
    else
         max = y;
    alert("max is: " + max);
    return max;
} 
var c=4,d=9;
var m = findMax(c,d);
```

Comment: 6 answers in a span of 2 minutes or less. D:

Comment: [Learn how to debug JavaScript](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) and [read a JavaScript tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your javascript isn't syntactically correct - `function findMax(var x, var y)` should just be `function findMax(x, y)`.

In general, if you write some javascript and *nothing* happens when you run it, it probably means something went wrong syntactically, and you should check your browser's Error Console. (In this case, it tells you that the function definition is where the error occurred, right on the first "var".)

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/p8Mk2/1/

```
function findMax(x,y) {
}
```

No var statement as explained here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Answer (score 1):

Your function syntax is wrong: you don't need `var` in the parameter list.

```
function findMax(x, y) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove var from arguments. Like this:

```
function findMax(x, y) {

//alert("x is:" + x + " y is: " +y);
    var max = 0;
    if(x>y)
         max = x;
    else
         max = y;
    alert("max is: " + max);
    return max;
} 
var c=4,d=9;
var m = findMax(c,d);
```

Answer (score 0):

you do not need to put a `var`

see updated fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/p8Mk2/2/